# Clara algorithm

Tags: clustering, algorithms

Here is an algorithm for clustering that calls Clara. I did not understand the final step. I mean step 3, 4.

1. For i ¼ 1 to 5, repeat the following steps:
2. Draw a sample of 40+2k objects randomly from the entire data set,2 and call Algorithm PAM to find k medoids of the sample.
3. For each object Oj in the entire data set, determine which of the k medoids is the most similar to Oj.
4. Calculate the average dissimilarity of the clustering obtained in the previous step. If this value is less than the current minimum, use this value as the current minimum, and retain the k medoids found in Step 2 as the best set of medoids obtained so far.
5. Return to Step 1 to start the next iteration.

Can anybody tell me that what is the next step after using PAM algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You apply PAM to a *sample*.

The next step is then to assign the entire data set to the clusters found by PAM, and evaluate the quality.

Of all these samples, you keep the best.